# How to download a SharePoint List that spans multiple web pages

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery, msbi

Using Power Query or Power BI (The M Language) I'm struggling to download an entire SharePoint List. The list is displayed in SharePoint as a web page that shows 1-100 of the complete list on the first page, then page 2 lists 200-299 and so on.

There are many pages and the entire list exceeds the 5,000 limit for querying.

Downloading the first list page is a snap, but trying to traverse to the second and subsequent pages does not work because the URL addresses are a mess that I have yet to understand.

Has any one figured out how to do this?

Comment: Although I'm not in touch with SharePoint, I think you should feed the address of the list, not of the resulting webpage. This list address would enable you to get the list not split into pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, writing your own SharePoint connector from scratch is definitely not simple!

Have you tried using M's built-in SharePoint library functions?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253322.aspx) suggests that `SharePoint.Contents`, `SharePoint.Files`, or `SharePoint.Tables` might be the solution.